# Infinite loop for python program

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a problem with this code, this program should keep allowing you enter students until the number of passes reaches 8 or the total number of students reaches 10.  However currently it just keeps asking for input and hence there is an infinite loop. How do I go about fixing this?

```
total_students=0
student_passes=0
student_failures=0

while (total_students <= 10) or (student_passes != 8):
        result=int(input("Input the exam result: "))
        if result>=50:
            student_passes = student_passes + 1
        else:
            student_failures = student_failures + 1
        total_students = total_students + 1

 print (student_passes)
 print (student_failures)

 if student_passes >= 8:
     print ("Well done")
```

Comment: change or to and?

Comment: But I only need either of those conditions to be true to end the loop.

Comment: @AbdullahJadoon You need _both_ conditions to be true to _stay_ in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change or to and. While both are true you continue:

```
total_students=0
student_passes=0
student_failures=0

while (total_students != 10) and (student_passes != 8): # != or <
        result=int(input("Input the exam result: "))
        if result>=50:
            student_passes += 1
        else:
            student_failures += 1
        total_students +=1

print (student_passes)
print (student_failures)
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why it waits for 11 inputs until the program terminates? It should be 10.

Comment: @AbdullahJadoon We could just change to != 10, as we are incrementing the value. When it hits 10 we dont want to continue. Your error was <= 10, which should be <10

Comment: brilliant thanks very much for your help. My work here is done.

Comment: @AbdullahJadoon Also notice you can use += 1 to increment, e.g. total_students +=1. Makes things more readable

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know you could do this. This is great, thanks!

Comment: @AbdullahJadoon No worries.. keep up the good work, posting code that show you tried and that we can test is a big plus. Also consider marking an answer as accepted if you are happy.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to revisit your code. I m not python expert, however I believe you should modify the condition for while loop.

such as while (total_students <= 10) or (student_passes <= 8):
this will resolve your problem.

```
total_students=0
student_passes=0
student_failures=0

while (total_students <= 10) or (student_passes <= 8):
        result=int(input("Input the exam result: "))
        if result>=50:
            student_passes = student_passes + 1
        else:
            student_failures = student_failures + 1
        total_students = total_students + 1

 print (student_passes)
 print (student_failures)

 if student_passes >= 8:
     print ("Well done")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **and** instead of **or** to meet your requirement.

```
total_students=0
student_passes=0
student_failures=0

while (total_students <= 10 and student_passes < 8):
        result=int(input("Input the exam result: "))
        if result>=50:
            student_passes = student_passes + 1
        else:
            student_failures = student_failures + 1
        total_students = total_students + 1

print (student_passes)
print (student_failures)

if student_passes >= 8:
    print ("Well done")
```